# Why does Apollo Server return an array with an errors object over an object

Tags: javascript, apollo-server

I've started using Apollo Server and it returns an array for a thrown error, with an error object. I am wondering why an array is returned instead of a single error object?

This link shows the format of the error response:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/errors.html

Comment: Because there may be more than one…? Note that it always talks about plural *errors*.

Comment: When would you throw more than one error object? Is that even a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Apollo Server is compliant with the GraphQL specification: https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Errors